# Pegar foto de galeria android diretamente

Tags: android, intent

Já pesquisei aqui e em outros lugares da internet mas não consegui localizar nada do tipo.
É possível restringir que as fotos selecionadas por um usuário venha apenas da galeria? Ex: Quando eu clico em uma foto de perfil e escolho a opção galeria eu ser direcionado diretamente para as fotos que estão na galeria e seleciono uma qualquer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente o seguinte:

Abrir opção:

```
 public static final int PICK_IMAGE = 1234;
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Selecione uma imagem"), PICK_IMAGE);
```

Recepção da imagem na Activity:

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(resultCode != Activity.RESULT_CANCELED){
            if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE){
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selectedImage.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Resposta do Thiago está correta, desse modo a galeria é aberta diretamente. Questão resolvida.